# Two processes running for each unicorn instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, memory-management, unicorn

I have setup my staging environment to have 10 unicorn instances. When I look at the memory utilization, I see 20 unicorn processes all consuming almost equal amount of memory

[image]

When I do

```
ps aux | grep unicorn
```

I only see 10 processes

Why do I see two processes for each instance of unicorn in the memory utilization?

Comment: Def something wrong here, you should only see the master and then 10 workers.  What does your init script look like?  And how is it started?

Comment: Probably you restart unicorn not properly? Thus master worker does not kill children process. What about if kill all process and start again. Does workers spawns twice?